# How to use a thread that updates a panel in a Windows forms in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, clock

I have class StillClock which is a Panel and is implemented as follows:

```
public class StillClock:  Panel {
  private int hour;
  private int minute;
  private int second;

  /** Construct a default clock with the current time*/
  public StillClock() {
      this.Size= new Size(200,200);
      this.Paint += OnPaint;
      setCurrentTime();
  }

  /** Construct a clock with specified hour, minute, and second */
  public StillClock(int hour, int minute, int second) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
  }

  /** Return hour */
  public int getHour() {
    return hour;
  }

  /** Set a new hour */
  public void setHour(int hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.Refresh();
  }

  /** Return minute */
  public int getMinute() {
    return minute;
  }

  /** Set a new minute */
  public void setMinute(int minute) {
    this.minute = minute;
    this.Refresh();
  }

  /** Return second */
  public int getSecond() {
    return second;
  }

  /** Set a new second */
  public void setSecond(int second) {
    this.second = second;
    this.Refresh();
  }

  /** Draw the clock */
  private  void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

      Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    // Initialize clock parameters
    int clockRadius =
      (int)(Math.Min(this.Size.Width , this.Size.Height ) * 0.8 * 0.5);
    float xCenter = Size.Width / 2.0f;
    float yCenter = Size.Height / 2.0f;

    // Draw circle
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    g.DrawEllipse(pen,xCenter - clockRadius, yCenter - clockRadius,
      2 * clockRadius, 2 * clockRadius );

    g.DrawString( "12", new Font("System", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black),  xCenter - 5f,   yCenter - clockRadius + 12f -10);
    g.DrawString("9", new Font("System", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), xCenter - clockRadius + 3f, yCenter + 5f - 10);
    g.DrawString("3", new Font("System", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), xCenter + clockRadius - 10f, yCenter + 3f - 10);
    g.DrawString("6", new Font("System", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), xCenter - 3f, yCenter + clockRadius - 3f - 10);

    // Draw second hand
    int sLength = (int)(clockRadius * 0.8);
    int xSecond = (int)(xCenter + sLength *
      Math.Sin(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
    int ySecond = (int)(yCenter - sLength *
      Math.Cos(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));

    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), xCenter, yCenter, xSecond, ySecond);

    // Draw minute hand
    int mLength = (int)(clockRadius * 0.65);
    int xMinute = (int)(xCenter + mLength *
      Math.Sin(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
    int yMinute = (int)(yCenter - mLength *
      Math.Cos(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));

    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue), xCenter, yCenter, xMinute, yMinute);

    // Draw hour hand
    int hLength = (int)(clockRadius * 0.5);
    int xHour = (int)(xCenter + hLength *
      Math.Sin((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12)));
    int yHour = (int)(yCenter - hLength *
      Math.Cos((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12)));

    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), (float)xCenter, (float)yCenter, (float)xHour, (float)yHour);
  }

  public void setCurrentTime() {
    // Construct a calendar for the current date and time
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // Set current hour, minute and second
    this.hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    this.minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
    this.second = DateTime.Now.Second;
  }
 }
```

I have to inherit class ClockAnimationUsingThread from class StillClock to develop an animated clock making use of a Thread object to set time of the StillClock every 1000ms.

I tried like this:

```
public class ClockAnimationUsingThread : StillClock
    {
        public ClockAnimationUsingThread()
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.setCurrentTime));
            thread1.Start();
        }
    }
```

and then :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var panel = new ThreadedClock_ClassLibrary.ClockAnimationUsingThread();
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
        }
    }
```

in the Form1 class but after starting it, it just generates the still clock and doesn't update it at all.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Refresh()` or `Redraw()` on the panel?  Unless you are using Invokes, I don't think the controls will update automatically (maybe not even then).  Notice how you are calling `this.Refresh()` in your hour setter, but not the others?

Comment: You're not supposed to try to update WinForms UI from a background thread that doesn't "own" that UI. Call .BeginInvoke instead.

Comment: you need to show your method "setCurrentTime"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Where exactly do you mean putting .Refresh() or .Redraw() ?

Comment: Look in your `setHour()` method.  See the `this.Refresh()` there? But also, heed the warnings from others that you may need to Invoke these operations.

Comment: I am pretty much sure that I have to use .Invoke somewhere but I don't know where. I have to declare a delegate somewhere so I can then Invoke methods in the GUI thread.

Comment: i just showed you in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to let the UI thread know that it needs to repaint the clock.  Just add:

```
  this.Invalidate();
```

Which is thread-safe, no need to invoke to the UI thread.  Do note that it is incredibly wasteful to burn up an entirely thread to just run a microsecond worth of code once a second.  A simple Timer gets the job done too, a lot cheaper.  And trivially solves your shutdown problem as well, you should not leave that thread running when the window is gone of course.

Comment: I agree with your answer...  I should have said that!  My answer is correct, I got sucked into trying to fix his code.

Comment: The code is just for practicing. In is not production or whatever. I was just wondering how I can achieve that by a Thread object that has to mess up with the GUI.

Comment: Well, pointing out that you are doing something very wrong while practicing ought to be relevant.  Could turn into a bad habit.  Please close your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of correcting this issue and showing how threads can work, do the following:

Do this:

```
public class ClockAnimationUsingThread : StillClock
{
    public ClockAnimationUsingThread()
    {
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.setCurrentTime));
        thread1.Start();
    }

}
```

Then this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var panel = new ThreadedClock_ClassLibrary.ClockAnimationUsingThread();
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.Start();
    }
}
```

I put it in a loop so the thread will continuously update every 1000ms, if you make the thread a background thread it will abort when the app is shut down.  If you don't want it to wait for that then you'd need to put some boolean property in the while loop and then set it to false when you close your form.

```
public void setCurrentTime() {
// Construct a calendar for the current date and time
while(true){
// Set current hour, minute and second
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
   this.hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
   this.minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
   this.second = DateTime.Now.Second;
   });

   Thread.sleep(1000);
 }


}
```

Comment: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Comment: move your code OUT of the constructor, create a NEW method named Start().  Put your thread creation code there and call Start() after your have added your panel etc...